# CommonsMail JavaMail - Falha ao enviar e-mail

Tags: java, jsf, email, gmail, javamail

Estou tentando enviar e-mail utilizando smtp da google com a lib CommonsMail, em uma aplicação web, porem sempre esta gerando uma falha.

Fiz uma app a parte e testei diversas configurações, na qual fui vendo em diversos outros tópicos. Utilizando porta 465 e 587 com e sem SSL e TLS, com SessionEmail do Glassfish 5, com o firewall do win10 desativado e ativado, em versões diferentes do commons mail, porem nada esta funcionando. 
 Obs: Marquei para Permitir aplicativos menos seguros acessar o gmail que criei pra teste.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse problema, seria muito grato, já não me restaram mais ideias.

Repositório Maven do Commons Mail

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
     <version>1.5</version>
 </dependency>
```

Código;

```
    public void enviarEmail() throws EmailException {
            Email email = new SimpleEmail();
            email.setDebug(true);
            email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
            email.setStartTLSRequired(true);
            email.setSmtpPort(465);
            email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("teste@gmail.com","teste123"));
            email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
            email.setSslSmtpPort("587");
            email.setFrom("teste@gmail.com");
            email.setStartTLSRequired(true);
            email.setSSLCheckServerIdentity(true);
            email.addTo("destino@gmail.com");
            email.send();        
    }
```

Erro

```
Warning:   org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.googlemail.com:587
javax.el.ELException: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.googlemail.com:587
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:187)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:150)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:96)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:839)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:870)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1418)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.googlemail.com:587
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
    at br.com.mail.mail.teste.EmailController.enviarEmail(EmailController.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.googlemail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2196)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você nao esta setando corretamente o host para gmail.
Exemplo:

```
email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
```

Possiveis soluçoes

1- Verifique se você está importando todos os jars corretamente:

dsn.jar, imap.jar, mailapi.jar, pop3.jar, smtp.jar.

2 - Verifique se o seu email está configurado para poder enviar emails:

Minha Conta > Login e Segurança > lá embaixo procure por "Permitir aplicativos menos seguros:" caso esteja desativado, é só ativar.

E aqui exemplos de como enviar utilizando a porta 465 e 587:

SSL/TLS (Port 465) -> email.setSSLOnConnect(true);

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
email.setSmtpPort(465);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
email.setFrom("user@gmail.com");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
email.addTo("foo@bar.com");
email.send();
```

STARTTLS (Port 587) -> email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
email.setSmtpPort(587);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);
email.setFrom("user@gmail.com");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
email.addTo("foo@bar.com");
email.send();
```

Comment: O meu amigo, desculpe a demora.. 
Eu tentei usando este host também, porem o  erro continua o mesmo.

Comment: editei a resposta, tenta ver se alguma funciona.

Comment: A unica coisa que não estava de acordo, eram os JARs, então coloquei as dependências que faltavam no maven e testei todas essas formas de enviar novamente em mais de versões do javamail e do commons. 
 O e-mail da google está configurado para enviar, corretamente no caso permitindo apps menos seguros.

Comment: e nao funcionou? que erro deu?

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou, continuou com o mesmo erro.
Esse teste estava usando seu exemplo "STARTTLS (Port 587) -> email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);"

Warning:   #{emailController.enviarEmail}: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587
javax.faces.FacesException: #{emailController.enviarEmail}: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587

Comment: Fico em duvida  se pode ser é algo nas dependencias/libs, SO, ou glassfish, pois fiz o mesmo meses atrás e funcionou, porem agora mudei para o gerenciador maven, pro glassfish 5 e estou trabalhando no SO win10, porem não encontrei nada bloqueando.

Comment: Tenta replicar este mesmo código em um outro ambiente para testar.

Comment: Funcionou o envio, porem só na classe de teste java que fiz, quando subo Glassfish  pra testar a app, o mesmo código no controller apresenta o erro Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465. Testei com mail.Session que configurei no Glassfish, mas também não funciona.

Comment: A porta de smtp do google não é a 465, mas sim a 587, tenta e veja se funciona

Comment: e confirme se os seus jar por exemplo o smtp.jar está no seu classpath.

Comment: Sim, adicionei as dependências que faltavas, os jar do dsn, smtp, gimap, activation, pop3, mailapi, commons-email,  javax.mail estão todas presentes, mesmo acreditando que não sejam todas usadas kk
Estranho que coloco setSmtpPort(587), mas pega porta 465. Um caminho que achei pra pegar a porta 587 foi colocar setSslSmtpPort("587"), porem também não tive sucesso, mas mudou o erro ;
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Comment: quanto a esse erro quando muda voce tem que habilitar o ssl seguro mail.smtp.ssl.enable para true

Comment: Agora funcionou, o ultimo problema se dava a versão do Glassfish que estava usando, no caso a 5.0. 
Depois de encontrar esse tópico https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/22436  passei teste com Glassfish 5.0.1 e com Glassfish 4.1.1, assim funcionou perfeitamente sem ter que alterar o código. 
Muito obrigado pela ajuda pessoal. TMJ